# WCF response is returned as text/html, not xml

Tags: wcf

I think something must not be correct with the serialization. My class is:

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    ...

    public User() { }

    public User(int id, string user_id, ...)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        ...
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class UserCollection
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<User> users { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int count { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int page { get; set; }

    public UserCollection() { }

    public UserCollection(List<User> users, int count, int page)
    {
        this.users = users;
        this.count = count;
        this.page = page;
    }
}
```

The API call:

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "?promotion_id={promotion_id}&page={page}&format={format}")]
    public UserCollection GetAllUsers(string promotion_id, string page, string format)
    {
        if (string.Equals("json", format, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;

        UserFactory factory = new UserFactory();
        return factory.GetUsersByPromotionID(int.Parse(promotion_id), (int.Parse(page) - 1) * 50, 50);
    }
```

The generated source:

```
<UserCollection xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/API.Library.Resources" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><count>0</count><page>0</page><users/></UserCollection>
```

It doesn't display the xml on the page because it says the response type is text/html. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of client are you using to invoke the web service?

You could try

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

Comment: I am using automatic format selection: <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />

Comment: It depends on the HTTP request sent by the client then. See [WCF Web HTTP Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510.aspx).

Comment: I am just accessing it in a browser. The request header says:

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Comment: The browser requests `text/html` with highest priority and it receives `text/html` from your WCF service. That's what `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled` is supposed to do. If you don't want this behavior, you need to disable it or tell your client, that it should request `application/xml` (as an AJAX request would do).

Comment: @Gene, I think the issue is that WCF is serializing the response as XML but indicating a content type of HTML. There is not an HTML-appropriate formatter, so the automatic format selection behavior should choose the next most appropriate accept header value, which would be XML.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml`?

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "?promotion_id={promotion_id}&page={page}&format={format}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
```

Comment: I am using automatic format selection: <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />

It's generating xml, just the response type is not correct for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the outgoing response format to be Json when you pass the format value as json.

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;
```

Have you made sure about sending the proper format parameter. Also try to inspect the request and response using Fiddler.